# Does "Expected Absolute Deviation" or "Expected Absolute Deviation Range" exist in stats and have another name?

Tags: probability, expectation, absolute-value, average, standard-deviation

So everyone is familiar with Variance and Standard Deviation from high school, but it seems no one has any familiarity with a philosophical justification for such weird, seemingly arbitrary measures.  After all, why square everything? Just to make it positive?

Anyway people use these measures to define what is meant by a particular value falling within "an expected range", or what is an "outlier" or "unusual data point".  Now I'm looking to define the same concept, but this time without using some arbitrarily chosen measure, but something that has a logical foundation - i.e., that *actually* means "expected range".

After some digging around I discovered Mean Absolute Deviation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_deviation#Mean_absolute_deviation

But what I really want is not the Mean Absolute Deviation, but the Expected Absolute Deviation.  It's easy to modify the formula on the wiki page to produce this, we just add in a p_i term so that each Absolute Deviation is multiplied by the probability of that x_i occurring.

But then after quite a bit of thought I realized that even that doesn't really define what a "outlier" or "reasonable result" really means.  This is because if we define the range of "normality" to be "Mean +/- Expected Absolute Deviation" we are ignoring the asymmetry of the distribution (if it's asymmetrical).  We need to compute a Upper Expected Absolute Deviation and Lower Expected Absolute Deviation giving a Expected Absolute Deviation Range.  For example a value of Mean + 0.1 might be within expectation for some distribution X, but Mean - 0.1 might not be due to an asymmetry.

So my question is, does such a line of reasoning already exist in statistics, and if so go by some other name?  I'd be very interested if such Ranges have been derived for various common distributions, particularly Binomial and Multinomial.  Any recommended books or links or literature much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Though yes the mean absolute deviation is a possible candidate to describe how data deviates from mean, it can be messy to work with. for example if we did define $Var(X)=E(|X-\mu|)$ with continous distirubiton in order to calculate this you would have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|X-\mu|f(x)dx$ which is quite messy to work with. Plus there are many nice properties that come from defining $Var(X)=E((X-\mu)^{2})$ like that this is equivalent to $E(X^{2})-(E(X))^{2}$, normal distribution is characterized by $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$. This is just a naive first look why I would prefer one over the other

Comment: Also in the wiki article you showed it talks about Mean Absolute Deviation (MAD) which I have used in forecasting models to compare model accuracy

Comment: Also instead of subtracting from mean, you can do what wiki article suggest and subtract from median to better account for a asymmetry

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, yes I'm aware variance is mathematically easy to work with, but in my work (writting artificial intelligence algorithms) I just want the most logically justified approach as this extra effort IME improves the performance of my AI.

Answer (score 1):

So this is not directly relevant to your final question, but it may help you understand a little bit as to why Standard Deviation/Variance are commonly used concepts.

Variance is one of the moments of a probability distribution. I'm not sure what your math background is, so I won't go into what moments really are, but what's important to understand is that if you have a probability distribution, the first moment is the mean, the second is the variance and the third is the skewness (which can help you deal with the asymmetry of a distribution).

The reason why this is important is that if you have a probability distribution (bounded), then the moments uniquely determine the distribution. Although the 3 moments above aren't enough to uniquely determine it, you can actually determine a fair amount about it with just those three values. If you used something other than variance to measure your spread, while it could be useful in many ways, it may not be as informative in generating the distribution function.

As mentioned in symplectomorphic's comment, there are other reasons too but the ability to use the moments of the probability distribution to determine the distribution is one of them.

Comment: I think it's wrong to say this is "the reason." There are many reasons. E.g., the mean minimizes the sum of squared errors; in the Hilbert space of mean-zero random variables, the standard deviation is the norm induced by taking the inner product to be the covariance; the Euclidean metric makes the variance and standard deviation geometrically natural as measures of error in multivariate statistics, which yields the orthogonal projections of regression.

Comment: Very good points. I'll amend to say "one of the reasons".

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanations as to the nice properties that variance has that makes it easy to wield mathematically.  I am aware that it is easier to use than absolute deviation, nevertheless my interest is in the logical justifications, and IMO more logical alternatives, not the ease of doing mathematics. Covariance is another example actually of a measure that is easy mathematically, but not as philosophically well justified as alternatives (particularly Mutual Information).

Comment: @samthebeast: it is not a question of what is "easy mathematically." Which measure of statistical dispersion you use depends on what you want to *do* with it. There are plenty of situations where people don't use the variance or standard deviation and instead use interquartile range, or range, or mean or median absolute deviation. I suspect the only reason you think people neglect the other measures of dispersion is that you haven't taken enough statistics and only seen the use of variance in elementary courses.

Comment: @Duncan, a random shot in the dark: is the result that the sequence of moments can be used to define/recover any "nice" distribution analogous/isomorphic to the result that polynomia can be used to define/recover any "nice" function? Or in other words, the powers of an object from 0 to infinity are special. The absolute value may not be so special?

Comment: I'd say you could draw an analogy between the two. Moments can be calculated for any function, they just happen to have special meaning in physics and statistics. For polynomials, the moments will be other polynomials, so you can often think of a set of polynomials as being the moments for another polynomial, thus using them to define the latter.

Answer (score 0):

For a random normal variable, I think you are looking for this (R code):

```
x <- replicate(1000000, rnorm(5, sd = 1), simplify = F)
y <- unlist(lapply(x, function(x) abs(sum(x))))
mean(y)
1*sqrt(5)*sqrt(2/pi)
```

This gives the mean absolute deviation (for a horizon of 5 observations).

```
require(extraDistr)
hist(y, breaks=100, prob=TRUE)
curve(dhnorm(x, sigma=1*sqrt(5)), col="darkblue", lwd=2, add=TRUE, yaxt="n")
```

The distribution of the absolute deviation is a Half-normal distribution.

```
quantile(y, c(0.1,0.9))
qhnorm(0.1)*sqrt(5)
qhnorm(0.9)*sqrt(5)
```

Then you can calculate the quantiles (10%, 90%); 80% of observations are expected to be within 0.281 and 3.678.